# Adding a Comment on an Inactive Question

Tags: discussion, comments

Is it correct to add a comment on thread that has not seen activity in a while?  Is it correct to do it when your addressing an issue in another comment, and not answering the main question?

I would gladly like your opinion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a comment and not an answer, absolutely. Even though that question may not pop into the recent bin, it will still notify the owner of whatever it is you're commenting on. Generally, that leads to edits or more answers, which then push it to the recent page.

Answer (score 1):

I do it all of the time, it is especially useful if you want the person who wrote it to revisit their question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is totally correct and encouraged! Note that:

- users will be notified of comments left on their posts
- comments do not "bump" the last activity date of the question, which is good